# How to get the ranks of two different colums in a table in my case?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table named db_points.

```
----------------------------------------
| Name    | Points | SPoints | RPoints |
----------------------------------------
| Max     | 240    | 50      | 1242    |
| Alvin   | 600    | 123     | 3012    |
| Amanda  | 234    | 1000    | 132     |
| Angela  | 50     | 514     | 4023    |
| Rudolph | 2000   | 230     | 1232    |
----------------------------------------
```

I need the rank based on ordering by TPoints (Points+SPoints), Points, SPoints, the rank based on RPoints and RPoints.

This would look like the following for Angela, Rudolph or Amanda.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| RankT   | Name    | TPoints | Points | SPoints | RankR | RPoints |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4       | Angela  | 564     | 50     | 514     | 5     | 4023    |
| 1       | Rudolph | 2230    | 2000   | 230     | 2     | 1232    |
| 2       | Amanda  | 1234    | 234    | 1000    | 1     | 132     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you see the rankings are different. The higher TPoints, the better RankT; the lower RPoints, the better RankR.

However I would need to get this in one SQL-query. This is what I got so far:

```
select  Rank,
        Name,
        TPoints,
        Points,
        SPoints
        RankR
        from    (select (@pos := @pos+1) pos,
            (@rank := IF(@prev = TPoints,@rank,@pos)) Rank,
            TPoints,
            Points,
            SPoints,
            Name,
            RPoints,
            select @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as RankR,t.*
            from    (select (@prev := SPoints+Points) TPoints,
                                SPoints,
                                Points,
                                Name,
                                RPoints
                                from db_points
                                order by TPoints desc)

                                as ll,
                                (select RPoints,
                                Name
                                from db_points where RPoints > 0 order by RPoints ASC) t,(SELECT @rownum := 0)
                                r)
                        as l
                where Name = '%s';
```

Hope that is understandable.

So far I have two working querys I need to put in one

```
select Rank, Name, TPoints, Points, SPoints from (select (@pos := @pos+1) pos, (@rank := IF(@prev = TPoints,@rank,@pos)) Rank, TPoints, Points, SPoints, Name from (select (@prev := SPoints+Points) TPoints, SPoints, Points, Name from db_points order by TPoints desc) as ll) as l where Name = '%s';
```

And this one

```
select  RankR
                from    (select @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as RankR,t.*
                        from    (select RPoints,
                                        Name
                                        from db_points where RPoints > 0 order by RPoints ASC) t,(SELECT @rownum := 0)
                                r)
                        a

                where Name='%s';
```

Hope you can read the code, im bad in formating mysql code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please give this a try

```
SELECT @rankT:=@rankT+1 as RankT,
       T.*
FROM
  (SELECT Name,
         (Points+Spoints) as TPoints,
         Points,
         Spoints,
         @rankR := @rankR + 1 as RankR,
         Rpoints
  FROM db_points p, (SELECT @rankR:=0)initialR
  ORDER BY Rpoints ASC
  )T,(SELECT @rankT:=0)intialT
ORDER BY TPoints DESC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6676c/2)

Then you can put this whole query as a subquery and do your outer select to look for `WHERE name like '%s'`

Comment: Thats working, incredible nice. Many thanks. Unfortunaly I cant give you an upvote yet.